# How to include predefined set of netbeans platform modules in maven project?

Tags: netbeans, maven

I am working on maven netbeans platform project consisting of several modules. I need to depend on some modules (say java.source module), but when I try to run the application, it reports, that required modules are not installed. And event despite I have dependency on java.source declared in my pom.xml

I think, that I have to tell maven somehow, to install (and turn on) these modules in the final assembled application before my module is loaded.

How could I do something like this?

**UPDATE:**

When I try to create complete netbeans application project from maven artifact and add Java Source API as a dependency into pom.xml... when I run the application, window with following message appears:

`Warning - could not install some modules: Editor Library 2 - None of the modules providing the capability org.netbeans.modules.editor.actions could be installed. Editor Indentation for Projects - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.settings.storage/1 was needed and not found. Editor Indentation for Projects - The module named org.netbeans.modules.options.editor/1 was needed and not found. Project UI API - No module providing the capability org.netbeans.modules.project.uiapi.ActionsFactory could be found. Project UI API - No module providing the capability org.netbeans.modules.project.uiapi.OpenProjectsTrampoline could be found. Project UI API - No module providing the capability org.netbeans.modules.project.uiapi.ProjectChooserFactory could be found. Editor Error Stripe Impl - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.errorstripe.api/1 was needed and not found. Java Source - The module named org.netbeans.libs.javacimpl/1 was needed and not found. Java Source - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.indent.project/0-1 was needed and not found. Java Source - The module named org.netbeans.modules.java.preprocessorbridge was needed and not found. Java Source - The module named org.netbeans.modules.options.editor/1 was needed and not found. Java Source - The module named org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api/1 was needed and not found. Editor Settings - No module providing the capability org.netbeans.api.editor.settings.implementation could be found. Diff - The module named org.netbeans.modules.options.editor/1 was needed and not found. 11 further modules could not be installed due to the above problems.`

Comment: I mean something like if you are creating netbeans platform application (without maven)... you can specify >platform< modules to be included in final application. How can this be made with Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error-message "Module dependency has friend dependency [...] but is not listed as friend" means that you need to specify an implementation version of org.netbeans.modules.options.editor. 
You can achieve this by editing src/main/nbm/module.xml to contain the following entry (I didn't use the actually needed values here. Make sure to find out which values to enter for id and explicitValue to satisfy the dependencies (You can find explanations / instructions in the article linked below):

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <id>org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-editor</id>
        <type>impl</type>
        <explicitValue>org.netbeans.modules.editor/1 = 201107282000</explicitValue>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm pretty sure that the following article will explain some issues and help you find out the needed values for id and explicitValue (language is english, author is me):

http://blog.macrominds.de/2011/08/open-favorites-per-default-in-netbeans-rich-client-platform-maven-standalone-application/

I'm currently having related problems with my application, so I might come back with a more concrete solution in a while.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is to grab a class that its complaining about, say "org.netbeans.modules.editor.actions" and go to the Add Dependencies and plug it into the Query field.
From there you should be able to tell which module you will need to include

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I was trying to do. I have parent maven project which has multiple modules, one of which is the main application and others are modules. Which project I should add these dependencies too? I have tried to add these dependencies using Add Dependencies, but it the modules themselves complained that their dependencies are not satisfied. I think, I have to include complete modules somehow ...

Comment: @Martin You should only add dependencies to the module that you're working on. the main project/platform app (the one with the orange icon) doesn't need to know anything about the dependencies of any of the modules living beneath it. Also remember that when you build your main project the files are being pulled from your local maven repo, not from the project/dist folder where ANT pulls them from - sometimes this causes an issue, as you have to build the module before you can run the main project.

Comment: still can't get it working... I am adding the dependencies just for the module I am working on. I followed this tutorial: http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/60/nbm-copyfqn.html (but wanted to make it with the maven)... So I tried to add deps for Java Source API. The application on startup throws a window containing information about missing modules, which should be installed.

Comment: I tried to package complete application with maven package, but when I look to the resulting archive, there are no *jar files or modules for java source api... should I tell Maven somehow to package these files into resulting zip file?

Comment: Now I tried to add all dependencies, but for some dependencies it complains: 'Module dependency has friend dependency on org.netbeans.modules.options.editor/1but is not listed as friend.'

Comment: @Martin could you possibly post your pom.xml for one of the modules? If we can figure out the problem with one then hopefully the others will be simialr issue